# ANOVA statistics.. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: statistics

My results when I input the data in Excel
[image: My results when I input the data in Excel]

Hawkes' result when they use statistical technology
[image: Hawkes' result when they use statistical technology]

I have no idea why my results are different from Hawkes, I tried using ANOVA single factor in excel, but I am still wrong. I used Regression as shown in picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9nms.jpg). Does anyone know how Hawkes was able to get the results shown in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAQFd.jpg)? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have (heroically) typed your spreadsheet values into my excel. When I compute the total sum of squared deviations on your column C, I get $36.22,$ like Hawkes gets. But you have your $y$ column as column A. So your spreadsheet is using age as the response, while Hawkes is using number of tickets as the response.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been staring at these problems for a long time with no clue on what I did wrong.